# Marshalling string array from ANSI C to string[] in C#

Tags: c#, c, marshalling

i am looking for a solution to marshal string array from ANSI C to string[] in C#.

Look like in ANSI C:

```
const char *cities[] = {"Moscow", "New York", "London"};
```

and in C# I have a System.IntPtr IntPtrCities and I want to convert this to a string list:

```
string[] citiesList
```

Also this solution inverted I need to...from string[] citiesList in C# to System.IntPtr IntPtrCities to ANSI C char ** cities.

I tryed Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi but it work only for one string and I dont know the string list size from the ANSI C layer.

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Comment: Your comment look like dont help me... :)

Comment: You cannot marshal an array directly from native to managed code without knowing the size of the array.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> You cannot marshal an array directly from native to managed code without knowing the size of the array.

Thank you. That is the important information!

In found this: https://limbioliong.wordpress.com/2011/08/14/returning-an-array-of-strings-from-c-to-c-part-1/

```
// This method transforms an array of unmanaged character pointers (pointed to by pUnmanagedStringArray)
// into an array of managed strings.
//
// This method also destroys each unmanaged character pointers and will also destroy the array itself.
static void MarshalUnmananagedStrArray2ManagedStrArray(IntPtr pUnmanagedStringArray, int StringCount, out string[] ManagedStringArray)
{
    IntPtr[] pIntPtrArray = new IntPtr[StringCount];
    ManagedStringArray = new string[StringCount];

    Marshal.Copy(pUnmanagedStringArray, pIntPtrArray, 0, StringCount);

    for (int i = 0; i < StringCount; i++)
    {
        ManagedStringArray[i] = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(pIntPtrArray[i]);
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pIntPtrArray[i]);
    }

    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pUnmanagedStringArray);
}
```